# How to get email of selected checkboxes in gridview on client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a grid view with 3 columns checkbox, name and email. I am trying from last day but couldn't succeed in getting email addresses of checked checkboxes on client side in JavaScript function.

Comment: What do you mean? Getting what where?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("table[id*=gridviewId]").find("input:checkbox:checked");
```

You said you already able to find the checkbox you want to find the checkbox in the next column try this.

```
checkbox.closest("td").next().find("input:checkbox:checked");
```

Comment: But Shankar I want to get next column value on click. I am able to access checkbox on clik but issue is I need value which is on next column. Plz guide.